# how to import my wallet from blockchain.info into bitcoin-qt?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, wallet, private-key, wallet-recovery

I have read the related discussions about how to import a wallet and though they are close, the answers does not help with this problem so I'm asking it here and now.

I have my bitcoin public address which was given to me by blockchain website when i registered, and the secret 12 words passphrase, and the blockchain wallet ID and my password for blockchain website. I can't login to the blockchain website because it sends a 2FA key to an old email for which I lost my password a long time ago. I have been asking for blockchain support because I can easily prove I am the account owner but I got no answer so far.

So, I'm looking to solve this problem. I'm running Linux Mint and I would like to import by bitcoin wallet into bitcoin-qt client. I know I need to use importprivkey into the debug console but I don't know how to get my private key since I can't login to blockchain website.

Many thanks for any help.